# Anaconda environment won't activate

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, activation, virtual-environment

I'm on Windows 7 using Anaconda 4.7.10.

On a command prompt after I entered

```
Python
```

I saw this:

> This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated.

I therefore followed the instructions to activate my Conda environment.

1. In CMD I checked the list of Conda environments

   ```
   conda env list
   ```

   Environment 'base' returned:

   ```
   base          * C:\Users\Linda\anaconda3
   ```
2. I added the path to my system variables
3. I activated my environment

   ```
    conda activate base
   ```
4. This returned:

   ```
    (base) C:\Users\Linda>
   ```

I am not sure where to go from here - am I expected to enter more prompts?

I closed the CMD and entered this again:

```
Python
```

It's still returning the Conda environment requiring to be activated message...so my activation actually didn't work. But I don't have any ideas as to how to continue with the activation process. Any ideas?

Comment: Conda activation is not like a software activation, it is just to enable the virtual environment you want to use, by default you would be under base environment unless you create a new one and activate it later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your step **4** already confirms that you were able to activate the base environment.

```
(base) C:\Users\Linda>
```

When an environment is activated, the default directory is **`"C:\Users\your-account"`**.

I would however, suggest you to use **Anaconda Prompt** instead of regular CMD.

If you want to use CMD, first activate the environment `C:\Users\your-account>activate base` and then enable python interactive interface `(base) C:\Users\your-account>python`

Comment: Thanks. I ran the C:\Users>Python command in Anaconda Prompt and it is not giving any error message. However, when I ran the same command in CMD it's still giving me the error message that the environment has not been activated. Does this matter?

Comment: Added instruction on what you should do and in what order in CMD to access python interactive-interface.

Comment: @PenguinZzz Please consider **accepting** and **voting up** the answer. Thank you.

Comment: That works, thanks a lot! I have voted for your answer but it seems like "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score". I have accepted your answer though.