# Warning "This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated"

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda, anaconda3

I installed `miniconda` on a Windows machine and whenever I type `python` in a PowerShell window to start up `Python` I get the following:

> This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
> not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
> please see https://conda.io/activation

I followed the link, but I honestly do not understand what I need to do...

Any tips?

Comment: Look through here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56679132/python-is-in-conda-env-but-has-not-been-activated-in-windows-virtual-env

Comment: Someone suggested adding the tag "python-3.x" (which I rejected). But it is something to consider. Why or why not?

Comment: This is a FAQ. There must be a canonical question somewhere. The low-scored ones here are what the search engines chose to list first. Related: *[CMD warning: "Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56623269/)*, *[Python is in a Conda environment, but it has not been activated in a Windows virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56679132)*, *[Python interpreter is in a Conda environment, but the environment has not been activated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69280974)*, -

Comment: cont' - *[Windows CMD: "This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65962598)*, *[Python Anaconda interpreter is in a Conda environment, but the environment has not been activated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62333071)*, *[Anaconda environment won't activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58924384/)*, and *[Conda environment is activated, but Python console says the environment has not been activated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62216927)*.

Answer (score 1):

In a command shell:

```
conda activate
```

And if this doesn't work yet:

```
conda init --all
```